# Python Flask Ordered dictionary is converted to String

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, flask

I wrote a webserver and have issues with deleting tasks with the bulkdelete function.

In the delete function, tasks is a list of OrderedDicts. However, in the bulkdelete function, type string is returned instead of OrderedDict which I do not understand. Is the content converted somewhere and how can I access tasks[count]["id"] in the bulkdelete function? Currently it returns

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Here you can see my whole code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
from collections import OrderedDict
tasks=[]

# Create a new task
@app.route('/v1/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    data = request.get_json()
    if "title" not in data:
        return bulkadd(data)
    completed=False
    if "is_completed" in data:
        completed=data["is_completed"]
    title = data["title"]
    tasks.append(OrderedDict((
        ('id', len(tasks) + 1),
        ('title', title),
        ('is_completed', completed),
    )))
    index = len(tasks)
    return json.dumps({"id": index}), 201


#List all tasks created
@app.route('/v1/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def getall():
   print(json.dumps({"tasks": tasks}))
   return json.dumps({"tasks": tasks}), 200

#Get a specific task
@app.route('/v1/tasks/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def getone(id):
    #This is wrong if one id is deleted and afterwards another one get
    i=0
    while i < len(tasks):
        if tasks[i]["id"]==int(id):
            return tasks[i], 200
        i=i+1
    return json.dumps({"error": "There is no task at that id"}), 404

#Delete a specific task
@app.route('/v1/tasks/<id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete(id):
    #loop that iterates through the list, searches for "id" in each dict and if they match, the dict is deleted
    i=0
    print(type(tasks))
    print(type(tasks[i]))
    while i < len(tasks):
        if tasks[i]["id"]==int(id):
            del tasks[i-1]
    return Response(status=204)

#(Extra Credit) Bulk delete tasks
@app.route('/v1/tasks/', methods=['DELETE'])
def bulkdelete():
    data=request.get_json()
    ids=data["tasks"]
    cleaned_ids=[]
    i = 0
    #print(tasks)
    while i < len(ids):
        cleaned_ids.append(ids[i]["id"])
        i=i+1
    print(cleaned_ids)
    for id in cleaned_ids:
        count=0
        while count < len(tasks):
            print(tasks[count])
            print(type(tasks[count]))
            if tasks[count]["id"] == id:
                print("delete")
                del tasks[count]
            count=count+1
    print(tasks)
    return Response(status=204)

#Edit the title or completion of a specific task
@app.route('/v1/tasks/<int:id>', methods=['PUT'])
def edit(id):
    data=request.get_json()
    i=0
    while i < len(tasks):
        if tasks[i]["id"] == id:
            tasks[i]["title"]=data["title"]
            tasks[i]["is_completed"]=data["is_completed"]
            return Response(status=204)
        i=i+1
    return json.dumps({"error": "There is no task at that id"}), 404

#(Extra Credit) Bulk add tasks
def bulkadd(data):
    content=data["tasks"]
    output=[]
    i=0
    while i < len(content):
        tasks.append(json.dumps({"id": len(tasks)+1, "title": content[i].get("title"), "is_completed": content[i].get("is_completed")}))
        output.append({"id": len(tasks)})
        i=i+1
    return json.dumps({"tasks": output}), 201
```

You can use this code for testing:

```
import requests
import json

def test_create_task():
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/v1/tasks', json={"title": "My First Task"})
    assert isinstance(r.json()["id"], int)
    assert len(r.json()) == 1

def test_list_all_tasks():
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/v1/tasks')
    assert isinstance(r.json()["tasks"], list)
    assert len(r.json()) == 1
    print(r.json())
    print(r.json()["tasks"][0]["id"])
    assert isinstance(r.json()["tasks"][0]["id"], int)
    assert isinstance(r.json()["tasks"][0]["title"], str)
    assert isinstance(r.json()["tasks"][0]["is_completed"], bool)
    assert len(r.json()["tasks"][0]) == 3

def test_get_task():
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/v1/tasks/1')
    assert isinstance(r.json(),dict)
    assert isinstance(r.json()["id"], int)
    assert isinstance(r.json()["title"], str)
    assert isinstance(r.json()["is_completed"], bool)
    assert len(r.json()) == 3

def test_update_task():
    r = requests.put('http://localhost:5000/v1/tasks/1', json={'title': "Test Task 2", 'is_completed': 'false'})
    print(r.content)
    assert not r.content

def test_delete_task():
    r = requests.delete('http://localhost:5000/v1/tasks/1')
    assert not r.content

def test_add_bulk_task():
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/v1/tasks', json={
   "tasks": [
      {"title": "Test Task 1", "is_completed": "true"},
      {"title": "Test Task 2", "is_completed": "false"},
      {"title": "Test Task 3", "is_completed": "true"}
   ]
})
    print(r)
    assert isinstance(r.json()["tasks"][0]["id"], int)
    assert len(r.json()) == 1

def test_delete_bulk_task():
    r = requests.delete('http://localhost:5000/v1/tasks/', json={
   "tasks": [
     {"id": 1},
     {"id": 2},
     {"id": 3}
  ]
})
    print(r)
    assert not r.content
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are passing a string as an index.

Comment: But in the delete function, this is working as well: if tasks[i]["id"]==int(id). So I do not understand why it should not work in bulkdelete @Errol

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your tasks[i] is a dictionary but in a string format.
From debugging your code I got this first line in the moment of the error:
(second line is what you want tasks[i] to be, notice first is a string not a dict) 
[image]

The issue is in the bulkadd function and possibly in the other add functions you have. When you use jsom.dumps({"key":"val"}) it will create a string formatted dict like : '{"key":"val"}'

I believe the problem is in the bulkadd function (and other add functions) when you use  json.dumps when appending to the task list. So if if you remove the main.dumps when appending it should solve the problem but you can keep the return json.dumps() as response for the flask app. By doing that task[I] will be a dict instead than a string formatted dict

```
def bulkadd(data):
    content=data["tasks"]
    output=[]
    i=0
    while i < len(content):
        tasks.append(json.dumps({"id": len(tasks)+1, "title": content[i].get("title"), "is_completed": content[i].get("is_completed")}))
        output.append({"id": len(tasks)})
        i=i+1
    return json.dumps({"tasks": output}), 201
```

```
def bulkadd(data):
    content=data["tasks"]
    output=[]
    i=0
    while i < len(content):
        tasks.append({"id": len(tasks)+1, "title": content[i].get("title"), "is_completed": content[i].get("is_completed")})
        output.append({"id": len(tasks)})
        i=i+1
    return json.dumps({"tasks": output}), 201
```

Answer (score 0):

Before looking into your problem I have a couple of remarks to your code. I would store the tasks in a dictionary for easier deletion afterwards instead of storing dicts in a list like you have now.

tasks would look like this:

```
tasks = {1: {'title': 'test', 'is_completed': False}, 2 : {'title': 'test2', 'is_completed': True}
```

An improved method for bulk deletion would look like this:

```
data=request.get_json()
for task in data['tasks']:
    del tasks[task['id']]
return Response(status=204)
```

Using all the while loops and counters is not really pythonic and cause you to have longer code that is prone to errors.

I hope you are able to improve the other parts of your code by following my example and if you need further help keep us updated!